# How to use the Tailwind UI's "Switch" with React form hook?

Tags: reactjs, forms, tailwind-css, react-hook-form

I've the following switch:

```
<Switch
  {...field}
  checked={enabled}
  onChange={setEnabled}
  className={TailwindHelper.classNames(
    enabled ? 'bg-indigo-600' : 'bg-gray-200',
    'relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500'
  )}
>
  <span className='sr-only'>Use setting</span>
  <span
    aria-hidden='true'
    className={TailwindHelper.classNames(
      enabled ? 'translate-x-5' : 'translate-x-0',
      'pointer-events-none inline-block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200'
    )}
  />
</Switch>;
```

with the following form:

```
const schema = yup
  .object({
    title: yup.string().required(),
    isOpen: yup.boolean().required(),
    focusTime: yup.number().required(),
    welcomeText: yup.string(),
  })
  .required();

const { register, control, handleSubmit } = useForm<IQueueProps>({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });
```

`IQueryProps` being:

```
interface IQueueProps {
  title: string;
  isOpen: boolean;
  focusTime: number;
  welcomeText: string;
}
```

I'm struggling to see how I can connect the switch with the react form hook.

I've tried this:

```
<Controller
  name="isOpen"
  control={control}
  defaultValue={false}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <Switch
      {...field}
      checked={enabled}
      onChange={setEnabled}
      className={TailwindHelper.classNames(
        enabled ? 'bg-indigo-600' : 'bg-gray-200',
        'relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500'
      )}>
      <span className="sr-only">Use setting</span>
      <span
        aria-hidden="true"
        className={TailwindHelper.classNames(
          enabled ? 'translate-x-5' : 'translate-x-0',
          'pointer-events-none inline-block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200'
        )}
      />
    </Switch>
  )}></Controller>
```

But it says:

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; checked: boolean; onChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>; className: string; onBlur: Noop; value: boolean; name: "isOpen"; ref: RefCallBack; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (Props<"button", SwitchRenderPropArg, "onChange" | "value" | "name" | "checked" | SwitchPropsWeControl> & { ...; })'.
  Type '{ children: Element[]; checked: boolean; onChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>; className: string; onBlur: Noop; value: boolean; name: "isOpen"; ref: RefCallBack; }' is not assignable to type 'Omit<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>, "onKeyPress" | PropsWeControl>'.
    Types of property 'onChange' are incompatible.
      Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.
        Types of parameters 'value' and 'event' are incompatible.
          Type 'FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement>' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<boolean>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onChange` handler is a function which takes the event as parameter. Your state setter `setEnabled` is a function which takes a boolean parameter. As the Typescript error suggests, these parameters are not compatible.

What you're looking for is to pass an event handler which sets the state inside the function body.

```
const toggleEnabled = () => {
  setEnabled(e => !e);
};

// ...

<Switch
  onChange={toggleEnabled}
  // ...
/>
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, that's what I was doing when I wasn't using react-hook-form, but I'm not sure how I could bind and toggle values?